# Closed curve divides into two or more regions compact and orientable surfaces with positive gaussian curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, surface-integrals

**Proposition**. Every closed curve divides into two or more regions every compact and orientable surface with positive gaussian curvature.

I need to prove this sentences using Gauss-Bonnet theorem, but I'm really lost. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: A surface with everywhere positive Gaussian curvature is topologically a sphere. The question now, is whether you want to use the Jordan curve theorem or not.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the curve is connected, we will prove that it divides in at least two components.

If not the complement $S\setminus C$ is connected. Cut $S$ along $C$ and adding  two copies of $C$ we find a closed oriented surface with boundary $C^{\pm}$. Consider two copies of this surface and glue them isometrically , gluing $C_1^+$ with $C_2^-$ , and $C_2^+$ with $C_1^-$(with obvious notations). The result is a closed connected  riemanian surface, and the integral of the Gaussian curvature is twice the integral of the Gaussian curvature on $S$, ie. $4.2\pi$, with Euler characteristic 4, which do not exist.

In fact Gauss Bonnet is just used to prove the well known topological theorem of additivity of the Euler characteristic $\chi (A \cup B)=\chi (A)+\chi(B)-\chi (A\cap B)$, for open sets.